# What are all the font weights available for google fonts?

Tags: css, google-webfonts

For example I could do an import like this:

```
@import url(http://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Roboto:100,400,900);
```

But could I also do one like this and would it make sense (Are the only valid values 100, 400, 900)?

```
@import url(http://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Roboto:100,200, 300, 400,500, 600, 700, 800, 900);
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Specifying Style and Weight for Google Fonts](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7256065/specifying-style-and-weight-for-google-fonts)

Comment: I did look at specifying style and weight but it did enumerate the possible weights.  The answer below that I accepted is the one I'm looking for.

Comment: Happy that you could find the answer. Cheers..!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It depends on the font. If you are at [Google Fonts](https://fonts.google.com/) and you select a font. Then select the `family selected` in the bottom right, then click the tab that says `customize` you can see all the font weights that the font will support.

Your current example is exactly how it will look if those font weights are supported. Here is `roboto` with all the possible font weights and styles.

```
@import url('https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Roboto:100,100i,300,300i,400,400i,500,500i,700,700i,900,900i');
```

The `i` stands for *italic*

To use these fonts you then do

```
.this-is-my-class {
    font-family: 'Roboto';
    font-weight:100; // or 100 - 900
    font-style: italic; // or normal 
 }
```

Answer (score 1):

May be this answer suitable to you

please go through this link

[Specifying Style and Weight for Google Fonts](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7256065/specifying-style-and-weight-for-google-fonts][1])

Answer (score 1):

Depends on what is generated when you select a Font [image]

This is generated when you select weights:
[image]